# How can I get the name of the drive on which the Windows is setup?

Tags: java, windows

The following code prints all drive names:

```
import java.io.File;

public class App{

   public static void main (String args[]) {

       File[] roots = File.listRoots();
       for(int i=0;i<roots.length;i++)
            System.out.println("Root["+i+"]:" + roots[i]);
   }
}
```

But I want only the drive name on which Windows is setup. How can I do this?

Comment: Why? Whatever you're trying to do is *either* 1.) a bad idea or 2.) something better left to dedicated installer code or 3.) both. I think there's an environment variable that gives the path to the windows install. And you can read those using `System.getenv()`.

Comment: *"How can I get the name of the drive on which the widows is setup by java code"*  You can't on OS X or *nix, which hints this might be best done in a non Java language.

Comment: This is [trivially easy to Google](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Microsoft_Windows). `System.getenv("SystemDrive")`

Answer (score 1):

1. Press *Windows + R*
2. Type `cmd`
3. In the console, type `set`
4. You can see the enviroment variables
5. Probably you'll see something like `SystemDrive`
6. So you can simply use `System.getenv("SystemDrive")`

Comment: `HOMEDRIVE` is where the user profile is. *On a default install* that's the same drive that holds the Windows installation, but that's not necessarily true for each install.